# How to enable different ACPI Sleep Modes with Asus UEFI BIOS

Tags: windows-8, motherboard, sleep, energy-saving, lifespan

I'm using a [new asus motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_LK/#specifications) which supports ACPI 2.0a, and am running Windows 8.  I'm trying to figure out how to maximize energy efficiency and component lifespan.  This computer is only used for a few hours a day, so should be in sleep mode or off for much of the time.  It uses Asus's sleek new UEFI bios with EZ mode and advanced mode, mouse support, etc.

I read [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/power-supply-protection-calculate-consumption,3066-4.html) about thermal shock and the various [ACPI sleep modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode).  That wikipedia article gives me the sense that I don't need to worry about changing the default sleep mode since it should already be S3 (suspend to RAM), but I noticed that my chassis's fans keep running during sleep which seems wasteful, and it seems to wake up suspiciously quickly.

I looked through the advanced settings in the BIOS and read through the manual and found nothing about managing sleep modes.  Are these still available in UEFI BIOS?  Also, if you have any tips about energy efficiency / component lifespan please leave them in the comments or include them as part of the answer.

Comment: Are your chassis fans plugged into the MB, or directly into the PSU? Since the system is off most of the time, why not shut it down, instead of sleeping?

Comment: According to the article the power savings are minimal, and then you have to wait for a full boot.  Also, I want to avoid as much thermal shock as possible but long sleeps might have the same effect...

Comment: Are your chassis fans plugged into the MB, or directly into the PSU?

Comment: Psu.  They do go off sometimes though during sleep.  I wonder if certain apps tell the os to not go into a deeper sleep sometimes.